# Redirecionar URL para um arquivo com htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento

Preciso fazer que quando acessarem o meu site assim `http://www.meusite.com.br/guarulhos` redirecione (ou abra) a página `http://www.meusite.com.br/guarulhos.asp` . Estou tentando com htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule /guarulhos http://www.novodominio.com/guarulhos [L,R=301]
```

Mas não está me dando nenhum retorno, redireciona para uma pasta **guarulhos** sendo que ela não existe.

Answer (score 0):

Achei esse tópico pois estava com um problema parecido. Para mim resolveu assim:

```
Redirect 301 /pasta /arquivo.asp
```